# C++ insert word at the beginning of a string vector using insert() method vector<>

Tags: c++, vector

I use a vector (string) book and a word list const char** liste mywords. I know the push_back() method to fill the book. But I would like to insert each word at the beginning of the book. I try this, but I do not understand why the book is still empty.

```
vector<string>::iterator begin=book.begin();
vector<string>::iterator end=book.end();
vector<string>::iterator pos = book.insert(begin, *mywords);
vector<string>::reverse_iterator rit=book.rbegin();

while (*mywords !=NULL) {
   for (rit=book.rbegin();rit != book.rend(); ++ rit)
   dico.insert(pos, begin, end);
 mywords++;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: `const char**` has no place in C++.

Comment: What is `dico`? Where does that come from?

Answer (score 0):

In the shown code, `pos`, `begin`, and `end`, are all iterators of `book`.

```
dico.insert(pos, begin, end);
```

This attempts to use these iterators, for some purposes, with some mysterious container called `dico`.

The `insert()` method of most containers typically takes an iterator for the same container. `pos` is not a `dico` iterator; as such this is most likely undefined behavior.

Comment: > Sorry,  there are some mistakes. It is not dico.insert(pos, begin, end) but book.insert(pos, begin, end).

Comment: I put a const** char in a vector<string> book with iterating.

Comment: In that case: `insert()` invalidates all existing iterators for a `vector`. After the first insert, none of these iterators are valid, any more, and the second time around this becomes undefined behavior.

Comment: what could I do? Do you have some advices?

Comment: After the insert(), reset all iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your code for the moment (since I don't understand it), if you have a `char **` containing a list of words (not sure why you'd do that, but let's move on) the easiest way to insert them at the beginning of a container would be to use  `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`:

```
std::deque<std::string> book;

for (char *word = mywords[0]; word != NULL; ++word)
    book.push_front(word);
```

If you really want to use a vector, then iterate it back to front, that's *fairly* easy as well:

```
std::vector<std::string> book;

for (char *word = mywords[0]; word != NULL; ++word)
    book.push_back(word);

// Copy the words in reverse to standard output:
std::copy(book.rbegin(), book.rend(), 
    std::ostream_iterator<std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: I want to use std::vector. Why iterator does not work? I get only a word in the book.

Comment: @Marie: `insert` isn't particularly hard to use--it just doesn't apply very well here.

Comment: In the book with push_back() words begin from 1st to last one. After using copy method, words are still at the same place in the book.

Comment: @Marie: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to reverse the order of the words in the vector? If so, consider using `std::reverse`.

Comment: That is ! I found ! do : book.insert(book.begin(),*mywords). All words are reversed from the last to one. Reverse() is not in std<vector>. Many thanks